# damaged capacitor and/or power amp

Tags: capacitor, damage, preamp

I have a [Mackie MR8 MK2](http://www.mackie.com/products/mrmk2series/) powered studio monitor that recently started making a horrendously loud humming and clicking noise (I mean LOUD, as in cover your ears).  Being just out of warranty, I decided to open it up.

I'm not an electrical engineer, so I'm not sure how to identify a blown capacitor, but I've attached a picture of one I suspect to be bad.  It is slightly bulged at the top, and a small bead of a brown rusty material is right in the center.

My questions:

1. Is this capacitor suspect judging from the picture?
2. What's the probability that this cap was damaged due to another component failure?
3. Taking my symptoms into account, would it be advisable to replace the power amp chips as well.
4. Are there any other commonly blown components I should replace/test as a precaution.  I don't want to replace the big capacitor just to have it blow again.

I realize answers my not apply directly to my model of preamp, but I'm just asking in general what would be good practice without having to test every single component.  I have limited access to lab equipment.

[image: pre-amp board]

[image]

Comment: What is the part number on the heatsink-mounted device at the top of the second image (the one with umpteen legs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sure looks blown to me.

You should definitely try just replacing the capacitors. There look to be two capacitors of the same size/model. Considering that one failed, the other is likely to fail too. (bad capacitors tend to come in batches)

---

The cause of the failure is harder to guess. Capacitors do tend to fail over time in hot environments, so it doesn't necessarily indicate a failure in other components, though it's not possible to completely exclude the possibility of another component causing the failure.

The best thing to do would be replace all the big electrolytics, and power the amp up on a variac with something that lets you monitor the current draw. If there is another failure, the amp will draw a lot of current.  If you're quick about it, It's generally possible to determine if there is another problem (which could damage the caps), and turn off the power before they're actually damaged.

This is a lot harder in semiconductor amplifiers then tube amplifiers, as semiconductor (e.g. transistor) amps tend to fail much more precipitously. Tubes are nice, as they are much harder to damage, and typically give visual warning that they're in the process of failure.

Comment: If you don't have a variac, rig up a power cable with a 60W lamp (not eco-bulb!) in series with the Live. It should barely glow. But if there's a serious fault, it will light and protect the amp.

Comment: Ha! That's an awesome way to test, I might just try it for mad scientist points.  I'm going to pick up the new caps today and I'll report back the result.

Comment: @uberdanzik - Bringing an amp (or any electronics that have not been powered for years/just repaired) on a variac is standard operating procedure for all the greybeards I know who do electronics work.

Comment: A few years ago, there was a rash of computer motherboard failures, caused by the manufacturers using some inexpensive electrolytic capacitors that turned out to be junk.  I was one of the victims.

Comment: I should note that bringing up electronics on a variac is a technique that only applies to devices that use a 60 Hz power transformer. Doing that to a switch-mode power supply could have interesting, and potentially damaging effects (though well-designed products should be fine).

Comment: Parts came today. I ordered the four biggest caps. Two 4700uf 50v and two 3300uf 35v.  Confirmed that the suspect cap above was bad by simply checking the ohms vs the other identical cap (there were pairs) and it was conducting way too much. I replaced all four large caps, triple checked my work, connected power (with no inputs), and blew the built-in protection fuse.  I'll ohm out the other caps tomorrow, but they looked fine visually.  If the other caps check out, what should I try replacing next?

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: Are you alluding to [the capacitor plague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/capacitor_plague)?

Comment: @davidcary: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Brian, great idea. In fact I remember working in a hifi shop many yrs ago and the owner had exactly that, a light bulb wired in series with the AC output for the DUT. When it glows bright, you know you have a problem in the DUT.  However since the poster is not electrically inclined (how to wire a light bulb in series), I would suggest removing the board and ohm the caps.  Use an ohmmeter to measure what you believe to be a good cap, sometimes DMMs read values that bounce around since you're testing it in-circuit.  A good cap won't necessarily measure open circuit, but maybe hundreds of ohms. If you then measure the suspect cap and read a steady 10 ohms or less, you need to replace the cap. And as someone already suggested, replace both.

Answer (score 1):

I had same kinda problem. My speaker started to made small cracks and pops once in while. Then it got worse and speakers was making noises all the time. Noise wasnt loud one but it was disturbing. I changed both big caps and problem was solved. I measured both caps and other one was faulty. Now everything works fine.